# Pure beginner javascript - array and map

Tags: javascript

Im brand new to javascript. I simply have an exercise where i need the array numbers to add each index to the next one.

The result should be:

```
var result = [4,8,15,21,11];
```

I tried something like this. It works on the first 4 indexes, however gives NaN on last since it doesnt have a next number to add to.

```js
var numbers = [1, 3, 5, 10, 11];

var result = numbers.map((x, index) => x + numbers[index + 1])

console.log(result)
```

Is there any smarter way to do this and how do i get index 4 to stay as 11? And please explain as im trying to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a perfectly valid way to do it. You can handle the last index by taking advantage of the fact that `numbers[index]` will be `undefined` (not an error) if `index` is beyond the end of the array, and `undefined` is a *falsy* value, so you can use `|| 0` to use `0` instead of `undefined` if it's there:

```
var result = numbers.map((x, index) =>  x + (numbers[index+1] || 0));
```

Live Example:

```js
var numbers = [1, 3, 5, 10, 11];

var result = numbers.map((x, index) => x + (numbers[index + 1] || 0));

console.log(result);
```

`||` is the logical OR operator, but it's a bit special in JavaScript: It evaluates its left-hand operand and, if that value is *truthy*¹, takes that value as its result; if the left-hand is *falsy*, the operator evalutes the right-hand operand and takes that value as its result.

In ES2020+ you can use the new [*nullish coalescing operator*](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing) (`??`) instead of `||`:

```
var result = numbers.map((x, index) =>  x + (numbers[index+1] ?? 0));
```

That will only use the `0` if `numbers[index]` is `null` or `undefined`, rather than if it's any falsy value.

---

¹ "truthy" and "falsy" - A truthy value is a value that evaluates to `true` when used as a condition (for instance, `if (x)` or `x || y`); a falsy value is a value that evalutes to `false`. The falsy values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course, `false`. All other values are truthy. (Except there's a special case on browsers: `document.all` is falsy for legacy reasons.)